# "AccessDenied" error on WorksheetCollection.onActivated event on Excel 2019 Desktop

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

My customer uses "WorksheetCollection.onActivated" event to update the information when the user changes the worksheet. they found that on some versions of the office while trying to set this event, the add-in is getting error "AccessDenied".

```
async function registerOnActivateHandler() {
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    let sheets = context.workbook.worksheets;
    sheets.onActivated.add(onActivate);

    await context.sync();
    console.log("A handler has been registered for the OnActivate event.");
  });
}
```

The code works fine on Excel Online and Mac, My customer does see the "Access Denied" issue on Excel 2019 Desktop version 16.0.10356.2006

The interesting thing is:
onAdded/onDeactivated event works fine on Excel 2019 desktop

Error screenshot: 
[image]

Does anyone have any insights on this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix has rolled out. So this issue should be gone.

====================================================================

This is a known issue and the fix is rolling out.

As a temporary solution, please add below code to the same batch of `sheets.onActivated.add(onActivate)` to work around.

```
// Call Write Operation APIs, bellow two line code equal to no-op.
let eventobj = sheets.onDeactivated.add(onDeactivate);
eventobj.remove();
```

For example, your code needs to be updated to

```
async function registerOnActivateHandler() {
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    let sheets = context.workbook.worksheets;
    sheets.onActivated.add(onActivate);

    // Call Write Operation APIs, bellow two line code equal to no-op.
    let eventobj = sheets.onDeactivated.add(onDeactivate);
    eventobj.remove();

    await context.sync();
    console.log("A handler has been registered for the OnActivate event.");
  });
}
```